# How to set the orientation of the app in ios automatically

Tags: ios, uiinterfaceorientation

I set the initial orientation of the app to UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight, but when I open the app with the physical orientation of UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft, it will show the interface of UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight first, then rotate to the UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft orientation.

How to make it open with the same orientation as the device?

Answer (score 0):

You have to instruct your UIViewController instances on which interface orientations are supported by implementing "shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation" as follows:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation)) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    } 
}
```

Comment: if (interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft
 ||interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
  return YES;
}   Isn't such way the same with yours? But it still will show the initial orientation setted in the .plist, then rotate to the orientation of the device. Why?

Comment: UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape is just a provided macro to shorten that code.

Comment: Yes, i know that, but my problem is that even i have made such check, when the app starts with the device's orientation is LandscapeLeft, my app's interface will still show in orientation of LandscapeRight, then rotate to LandscapeLeft as soon. What i want is that the app show its interface with the same orientation of the device, device is LandscapeLeft, the app should LandscapeLeft, too.